# nuxt router.js rewrites after running npm run dev in vuejs app

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, nuxt.js

i' m in a project (has been coded by someone else) , it has router.js file that include all app's routs , and created in a function , code below

```
export function createRouter() {
  return new Router({
    mode: 'history',
    base: decodeURI('/'),
    linkActiveClass: 'nuxt-link-active',
    linkExactActiveClass: 'nuxt-link-exact-active',
    scrollBehavior,

    routes: [{
      path: "/login",
      component: _32e99e0f,
      name: "login"
    }, {
      path: "/orders",
      component: _5838bb72,
      name: "orders"
    }, {
      path: "/profile",
      component: _1a272ccf,
      name: "profile"
    }, {
      path: "/orders/new",
      component: _2c62ddc3,
      name: "orders-new"
    }, {
      path: "/orders/new/:step",
      component: _91e13fc8,
      name: "orders-new-step"
    }, {
      path: "/orders/:order",
      component: _14e0655f,
      name: "orders-order"
    }, {
      path: "/",
      component: _6941faf8,
      name: "index"
    }],

    fallback: false
  })
}
```

this function has been import and called in a function named createApp in index.js file, code below

```
async function createApp(ssrContext) {
  const router = await createRouter(ssrContext)

  const store = createStore(ssrContext)
  // Add this.$router into store actions/mutations
  store.$router = router
  .
  .
  .
}
```

it seems stores in an array , and used globally that seems ok ,
the issue comes when i change one of routes and make a new one , like

```
export function createRouter() {
  return new Router({
    mode: 'history',
    base: decodeURI('/'),
    linkActiveClass: 'nuxt-link-active',
    linkExactActiveClass: 'nuxt-link-exact-active',
    scrollBehavior,

    routes: [{
      path: "/new-route",
      component: _newname,
      name: "newRoute"
    },
   . 
   .
   .
```

when i use `npm run dev` or `npm run generate`, the function and its data has been overwrited and came back to the original code . 
can anyone please make me a sense of what is happening hear , i'm so new in vue.js ;) and need some kindness .

Comment: tldr: Nuxt.js automatically generates the vue-router configuration based on your file tree of Vue files inside the pages directory. https://nuxtjs.org/guide/routing

Comment: OMG! thanks @LawrenceCherone , u saved me after a confusing week.